# Splitting of states in Semiconductor

Tags: semiconductor-physics

According the book "Semiconductor Physics and Devices by Donald A. Neamen",

> We have seen previously that, at any energy level, the number of allowed quantum states is relatively small. In order to accommodate all of the electrons in a crystal, we must have many energy levels within the allowed band. As an example, suppose that we have a system with 10^19 one-electron atoms and also suppose that, at the equilibrium interatomic distance, the width of the allowed energy band is 1 eV. For simplicity, we assume that each electron in the system occupies a different energy level and, if the discrete energy states are equidistant, then the energy levels are separated by 10^-19 eV. This energy difference is extremely small, so that for all practical purposes, we have a quasi-continuous energy distribution through the allowed energy band. ",

Shouldn't a factor of 2 be multiplied accounting of 2 spins of electrons? Because each Atom would have two states. If not, why a factor of two was multiplied while deriving the formula for density of states? Where is the flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: Depends on whether you consider spin up/down as different states to occupy. Some crystals (I’m looking at you, bcc Fe) make it very clear that spin up and down are separated from each other.